# Should I pass pointers as parameters

Tags: go

I'm working with pointers for the first time and I have what is probably a simple question.

I have two functions `main` and `other`. If I have a variable in the `main` function that I would like to make available in the `other` function should I pass it as a parameter or is that defeating the object of pointers?

**OPTION 1**

```
func main() {
    myVar := "hello world"   
    other(&myVar)
}

func other(s *string) {
    println(s)
}
```

**OPTION 2**

```
func main() {
    myVar := "hello world"
    other()   
}

func other() {
    println(*myVar) //Is myVar even accessible here?
}
```

Comment: you can try it out [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/AQi-KLMhS7)

Comment: None of your option is common. Just pass the value. And please: Take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you've got downvoted... The second option will not compile because inside the other function myVar is not present. Every variable has a scope. The variable is only accessible inside it's scope.

*(If you like to learn more about the diffrent scopes in go I recommend the following link https://www.golang-book.com/books/web/01-02 - scroll down to scope. It's well explained with a nice visualization.)*

To make things a bit clearer, I add some examples:

**OPTION 1 - pass the pointer value**

This is what you had. But make sure to dereference your pointer to get back the actual string. Your version was printing the pointer itself (mem-address). See my change (*s instead of just s)!

```
func main() {
    myVar := "hello world"
    other(&myVar)
}

func other(s *string) {
    println(*s)
}
```

**OPTION 2 - pass the variable value**

This is probably what you meant with your option 2.

```
package main

func main() {
    myVar := "hello world"
    other(myVar)
}

func other(myVar string) {
    println(myVar) 
}
```

**OPTION 3 - make myVar global**

Maybe this is what you wanted to do in your second option. myVar is global here (or as in golang lingo, myVar has a *package*-level scope), therefore accessible inside the other function.

```
var myVar = "hello world"

func main() {
    other()
}

func other() {
    println(myVar)
}
```

**As to your question wether you should pass the value or a pointer to the variable:**

In general you pass pointers, if your function needs to be able to edit the value. Also when the variable itself is really big and it would cost time / ressources to pass the value you can pass the pointer which is more efficent.